# Javascript code doesn't work on Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I have a script running on my index.html page. It works perfectly for other browsers except Safari. Any idea why? 
My script check the input of the User and see if it matches any of the postal codes in the array. If it matches it'll redirect user to a new page. If it doesn't match, i'll show a hidden message.

```
<script>
  // CHECK IF USER WITHIN DELIVERY AREA
  function checkAnswer(){
        var postalCode = ["V5K", "V5M","V5R","V5S","V5L"]
    var response = document.getElementById('answer').value;
    for (var i = 0; i < postalCode.length; i++) {
      if (response.substring(0,3).toUpperCase() == postalCode[i]) {
        location = '/postal-code-area';
        break 
      } 
      if (postalCode.every(elem => elem !== response.substring(0,3).toUpperCase())) {
            $("#postal-code-not-found").css("visibility","visible");
            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#postal-code-not-found").css("visibility","hidden");
            },3000);
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: What version of safari?

Safari has very minimal ES6 support...

https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#safari71_8

Comment: @Koborl Safari Version 9.0.1

Comment: Safari 9 doesn't support arrow functions. You can transpile it using babel and it should work.

https://babeljs.io/repl/

Comment: @Koborl Worked like a charm! Thanks

Comment: The very first step of debugging should be to open the JavaScript error console.  Safari makes you jump through hoops to do this, but this should help:  https://www.wickedlysmart.com/hfjsconsole/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can change:
`$("#postal-code-not-found").css("visibility","visible");
  setTimeout(function() {
      $("#postal-code-not-found").css("visibility","hidden");
  },3000);`

to:
`$("#postal-code-not-found").css("display","block");
  setTimeout(function() {
      $("#postal-code-not-found").css("display","none");
  },3000);`